# Collapse backref page ranges

Tags: bibliographies, citing, back-referencing

Backref gives me "pp. 99, 100, 101, 102, 103" if that is where this bibitem is referenced. I need to produce "pp. 99-103". How can I get that?

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[pageref]{backref}
\begin{document}
\newpage
\cite{Foo}
\newpage
\cite{Foo}
\newpage
\cite{Foo}
\newpage
\cite{Foo}
\newpage
\cite{Foo}

\begin{thebibliography}{999}
\bibitem{Foo} The. Author, {\em The Title}, The Publisher, 1999.

\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please keep in mind that there are several bibliography packages for LaTeX and also several possible ways how the backreferences can be obtained. In order to be able to give a good answer here it is crucial to know which packages you use. Please show us a short example document with a citation and a few backreferences that you want to compress, a so-called MWE (https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864 and https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864).

Comment: OK, a small working example:\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[pageref]{backref}
\begin{document}

\newpage\cite{Foo}
\newpage\cite{Foo}
\newpage\cite{Foo}
\newpage\cite{Foo}
\newpage\cite{Foo}

\begin{thebibliography}{999}
\bibitem{Foo}
The. Author, {\em The Title}, The Publisher, 1999.

\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}

Comment: I seem to be unable to use <enter>. As soon as I type a newline, the comment is posted.

Comment: @sonja I've added and formatted your example into your question. In the future, you may use the 'edit' button under your question to make edits and to add code (format it with the `{}` button).